# Linked Server in SQL Server Throwing Error

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I am trying to establish a connection between 2 Server. 
IP1 - SQL Server 2008R2
IP2 - SQL Server 2019
I can telnet via port 1433 to these 2 IPs from my system.

I am in My System. I am connected to IP1 using SSMS and executing below queries:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver 'IP2';
exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'IP2', 'FALSE', NULL, 'username', 'password';
```

These above statement ran successfully.

-- Test

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [IP2].DBName.sys.columns
```

This statement throws below error.

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "IP2" returned message "Client unable to establish connection".
Msg 10054, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: The error doesn't mention it but I suspect your SQL Server 2008 R2 instance doesn't support TLS 1.2 connectivity. The `SQLNCLI` (SQL Server Native Client) provider is somewhat deprecated. Are you able to use the `MSOLEDBSQL` provider and then include `Encrypt=no;` in the `@provstr` parameter? Ref: [sp_addlinkedserver (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql)

Comment: I think, it has been caused by firewall restriction